# Conservation of energy when a block ascends a curved wedge

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation, work, free-body-diagram

[image: diagram]

With reference to the above diagram:

When the block ascends on the wedge, wedge also starts moving in forward direction due to the normal force (horizontal component) applied by the block. Block keeps on ascending until it's velocity with respect to wedge becomes zero (maximum height).

For the above motion described i.e. till the block reaches maximum height — It is said that total mechanical energy of the system is conserved (system = block + wedge).
But isn't the component of weight of block ($mg$) along wedge's surface doing work when it ascends the wedge? and indeed weight ($mg$) here is an external force here. For wedge, I understand that work done by gravity will be zero since displacement and force are perpendicular but what about the block ascending?

How work done by external forces (mainly gravity) is zero here (and total mechanical energy is conserved) ?

Comment: "But isn't the component of weight of block (mg) along wedge's surface doing work when it ascends the wedge ?" Describe this work.

Comment: In order for mechanical energy to be conserved, you need to include the Earth in the system.

Comment: @BobD $dW = mg  \sin \theta .dx$ where mg sin$\theta$ is the instantaneous component of block's weight along wedge's surface. $\theta$ being the instantaneous angle between wedge's surface and horizontal. the above described work will be negative since force and displaced (dx) are in opposite direction.

Comment: @BobD Also, if someone tell you to find the maximum height attained by the block for above situation, you will too, apply energy conservation along with momentum conservation to get the answer. So how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mechanical energy is conserved because mechanical energy is kinetic energy and potential energy.

When the block reaches its highest point, you have a totally inelastic collision:

The intermediate state kinetic energy

$$ T=\frac 1 2 (m+M)u'^2 $$

is minimized with the constraint that momentum is conserved:

$$ mu = (m+M)u' $$

The missing kinetic energy is stored as gravitational potential energy:

$$ mgh = \frac 1 2 mu^2 - T $$

and is recoverable when the block slides back down.

Comment: what about the external force doing work ? (gravity on smaller block)

Comment: @Spencer $\int_0^k mg dh = mgh \ne 0$.